# Possible cause for not sending SMS messages on one of two Moto Gs

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms, motorola-moto-g

I have two Motorolas Moto G:

- from the same line (new, purchased in the same place in one month period),
- with the same operating system -- now Marshmallow 6.0.1,
- using exactly the same GSM provider / GSM network,
- used in the same location and thus probably connecting to the same network cell,
- connecting to exactly the same WiFi networks (if that matters),
- having exactly the same phone configuration,
- even having exactly the same set of applications installed.

For past 2-3 months one of these two Motorolas has a constant problem with sending SMSes. I just can't count number of times I saw "Message not sent. Tap to retry" message on one of these Moto Gs, while on the other one I didn't see this message even once so far.

What can be possible source of this problem or what steps can I undertake to try to investigate it?

Comment: Guess here - do you have hangouts installed on the device from which SMS don't go. If yes, and it is a user app , uninstall it and try, From your description, I don't think your device is rooted, else Hangouts could be uninstalled even if system app

Comment: This Notification always on my Moto X Play along with red triangle but the funny thing is that a) Message is actually sent and b) Internet revealed that this is because Google Hangouts. Being rooted, I froze that app and now I don't have that notification

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but actually this guess is wrong. I don't have Hangouts installed and messages are not being sent randomly. It's around 20% of all messages that are not delivered at once and must be resend 2-3 times.